# Malformed Html, function in onclick

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm struggling to find workaround with GAS.
This very simple, work perfectly fine in this snippet or in any html tool.

```html
<a href="#" onclick=dummyFunc(foo)>OK</a>
<a href="#" onclick=dummyFunc("param")>not OK</a>
```

But google app script dont reconize the seconde line like valid html. If you put it in `HtmlService.createHtmlOutput()` or any other function that create html from the `HtmlService` it will raise `Exception: Malformed HTML content`.

**EDIT**

The only way I find to make it work is using:

```
<script>var param="param";</script>
<a href="#" onclick=dummyFunc(param)>OK</a>
```

Thank for you help. Have a great day.

Comment: Rollbacked because the tags are still relevant without regarding the core of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, your html is not valid.
Here's the right way :

```
<a href="#" onclick="dummyFunc('param')">OK</a>
```